# Node Readable stream woes

Tags: node.js, fs

I was looking at this pretty nifty section of examples on streams.

https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/10026630

The example for readable looks like so:

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable
var inherits = require('util').inherits

function Source(content, options) {
  Readable.call(this, options)
  this.content = content
}

inherits(Source, Readable)

Source.prototype._read = function (size) {
  if (!this.content) this.push(null)
  else {
    this.push(this.content.slice(0, size))
    this.content = this.content.slice(size)
  }
}

var s = new Source("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
console.log(s.read(10).toString())
console.log(s.read(10).toString())
console.log(s.read(10).toString())
console.log(s.read(10).toString())
console.log(s.read(10).toString())

// The quick 
// brown fox 
// jumps over
//  the lazy 
// dog.


var q = new Source("How now brown cow?")
q.pipe(process.stdout);
```

what really confuses me is that the point of streams is ***not*** to buffer everything up in memory at once, *as well as* to provide some asynchrony so that not everything about piping a stream is processed in the same turn of the event loop.

```
  const writable = new stream.Writable({

        write: function(chunk, encoding, cb){

            console.log('data =>', String(chunk));

            cb();
        }

    });


    var readable = new stream.Readable({

        read: function(size){

            // what do I do with this? It's required to implement

        }
    });

    readable.setEncoding('utf8');

    readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length, String(chunk));
    });

    readable.pipe(writable);

    readable.push('line1');
    readable.push('line2');
    readable.push('line3');
    readable.push('line4');
```

But what I don't understand is, how am supposed to implement the read method on readable?

It seems like I would be implementing read completely differently then the example, so something seems to be off.

How do I read in data with a readable stream manually?

Answer (score 0):

Well I knew something was a bit off, I believe this is closer to the canonical way to do this:

```
    const writable = new stream.Writable({

    write: function(chunk, encoding, cb){

        console.log('data =>', String(chunk));
        cb();
    },

    end: function(data){
        console.log('end was called with data=',data);
    }

});


var index = 0;
var dataSource = ['1','2','3'];

var readable = new stream.Readable({

    read: function(size){
        var data;
        if(data = dataSource[index++] ){
            this.push(data);
        }
        else{
            this.push(null);
        }
    }

});

readable.setEncoding('utf8');

readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length, String(chunk));
});


readable.pipe(writable);
```

I don't believe the developer should call `read` explicitly; `read` is to be implemented by the developer, but not called. Hopefully this is correct. My only question left is why `end` was not called in the writable stream. I'd also be curious as to why read does not take a callback.